# How to deal with two sockets, when one socket is doing things in background

Tags: c++, c, sockets, tcp, udp

I'm creating program using sockets. I have two sockets: one for listen, and one for connection to external server. 
One, which is connected to server read data in infinite loop, server is constantly streaming data to my program, and in "real time" I write that data to output.

The second one is listening to messages -when message is PAUSE, program should stop reading data from first socket.

How to deal with such a situation? Poll()/select() isn't solution, because, these two sockets needs to work simultanously, and when poll detects data to read from socket one, than I'm going into infinite loop, and stop listening on a second socket.

I thought about breaking infinite loop of reading data from server in constant period of time, but then, when message comes it has to wait.

Please help me!

Comment: I don't follow why poll/select aren't solutions here - why do you "go into infinite loop and stop listening"?  Multiple threads are another possible solution here, though.

Comment: Use multithreading where one thread is constantly listening as required. Alternatively poll the socket periodically and enqueue received data to some sort of buffer/queue.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth poll/select  waits until one or more of the file descriptors become "ready", my first socket is always ready, what should "say" the second one for that?

Comment: @Michocio, select/poll allow for multiple sockets to be "ready" at a single point in time (to my knowledge). You will just sequentially go through them.

Comment: @thcpx What do you mean by "be "ready" at a single point in time"?

Comment: Any "stop reading data from the socket" is suspect, IMO. You typically want to continue reading the data, and "pause" means either throw away the data, or else update the data but don't update the display. The question is: what should happen when you un-pause? For example, assume your display shows the last 15 seconds of data. If you pause for 5 seconds, should that show as a "hole" in the data, or when you un-pause, should the data from the 5-second pause be shown?

Comment: @Michocio Once a call to select returns you iterate through all the file descriptors to see if new data arrived for them. After you looped though all of them, you start select again. You don't stop checking just because socket one already received something, but continue checking the other sockets every time as well. - As long as your network interface receives the packets, they will arrive in your program. I don't quite get why you think there will be starvation?

Comment: @thcpx , the point is that I if I read data from stream byte after byte, I should poll every time after reading byte. Too many polls here

Comment: @Michocio Why would you want to read byte after byte? Frankly there are far too many (quite expensive) reads here (: You can use buffers to read larger chunks of information. Data arrives in packets and I think it is safe to assume they are all larger than 1 byte.

Answer (score 4):

My best recommendation would be [*epoll()*](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html), since I use it, but I'm sure that you can do it also with *poll()* or *select()*. Read the manual and give it a try.

[Here](https://banu.com/blog/2/how-to-use-epoll-a-complete-example-in-c/) is a good example of how to use it.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

In your circumstance I would use `epoll` with multiple threads. Of course you would have to deal with all the fun potential issues with multithreading such as starvation or deadlock. I found [this](http://www.csh.rit.edu/~rossdylan/presentations/EpollMT/#14) resource which could help you implement such a solution.

If you need more information on `epoll` itself check out the [epoll section](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html#nb.epoll) in the c10k problem. There is also this [link](http://kovyrin.net/2006/04/13/epoll-asynchronous-network-programming/) that speaks of epoll in async programming.